# python: combine values in one column on the basis of ids in another column

Tags: python

I need to combine values in second column of a tab delimited file based on the ids in first column. The example is given below. What is the fastest way to do this. I can do it using for loop, going through each line, but I am sure there is some smart way to do it, which I am not aware of.

```
596230  Other postop infection
596230  Disseminated candidiasis
596230  Int inf clstrdium dfcile
596230  Pressure ulcer, site NOS
2846079 Schizophrenia NOS-unspec
7800713 CHF NOS
7800713 Chr airway obstruct NEC
7800713 Polymyalgia rheumatica
7800713 DMII wo cmp nt st uncntr
```

into

```
596230  Other postop infection, Disseminated candidiasis, Int inf clstrdium dfcile, Pressure ulcer, site NOS
2846079 Schizophrenia NOS-unspec
7800713 CHF NOS, Chr airway obstruct NEC, Polymyalgia rheumatica, DMII wo cmp nt st uncntr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your text in a file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
items = defaultdict(list)
with open("myfile.txt") as infile:
    for line in file:
        id, text = line.rstrip().split("\t")
        items[id].append(text)
for id in items:
    print id + "\t" + ", ".join(items[id])
```

This does not keep the original order of your `id`s, but it does keep the order of the texts.

Answer (score 1):

If they're already sorted, you can use `itertools.groupby()` on the split lines to gather them up. If they're not sorted, then sort them first.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider the [Python csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to parse your file because you can set it to use a character other than a comma (such as a tab, `\t`) as the separator.
The basic example is something like this:

```
import csv
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

From there you can use one of the options already suggested to group all items with the same number together.